# JW Player adding custom button tooltipOverlay not shown when hovered

Tags: actionscript-3, jwplayer

I use this repository : https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer
In ControlbarComponent.as I have modified some code to adding audio selection button with TooltipMenu for using with HLS.

**The "audio" button was shown on controlbar, however when hover the tooltipmenu not show on audio button.**
I had override method TooltipOverlay.positionX() and TooltipOverlay.positionY() follow as:

```
super.x = 100;
super.y = 100;
```

Then, audioOverlay show fine on the top left corner of player with 3 options I have added before.
If not, the overlays not show anytime.
I debug by trace audioOverlay position by this method:

```
public function get currentPosition():String {
        return ((contentDimensions.width + borders.left.width + borders.right.width - arrow.width) / 2) + _offset + "x" + Math.ceil(_y - (_inverted ? -arrow.height : (borders.top.height + borders.bottom.height + arrow.height + contentDimensions.height)));
    }
```

Now, it return 39x-63 (with y = **-63**). Seems this is reason.

Can you tell me what i missed ?

Comment: This is the open source player, so the HLS code is not included in this source repository. Does the issue happen if you don't use HLS audio?

Comment: Because my streaming includes 2 types of audio : original audio and voice-over audio.

Comment: Hi @EthanJWPlayer, can you give me a tip ? This is demo of that I described below : http://demo.trinvh.com/flash/index.html - http://demo.trinvh.com/flash/index2.html

Comment: I am a little confused here. How are you running HLS with the free player?

Comment: First, thank for your awesome work, @ethan. I find out another repository here https://github.com/mangui/flashls and I worked hard to make it works with jwplayer. I saw that it support audio index for hls, and I am finding a solution for this :). Anyway, can you help me out of above issue?

Comment: Hey, i missed to call positionOverlay(_audioOverlay, getButton('audio')). After doing that, it display fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
+ "x" +
```

you added the string to number ) and this part is string 39x

Comment: This is an available function so i think its not problem.

Comment: @Valerii I think you've misunderstood the question, the question I think was about why the `y` coordinate is negative.

Comment: ouch ) in this case i think you only should to delete "-" )) b/c height is always >0

Comment: [code] _inverted ? -arrow.height : (borders.top.height + borders.bottom.height + arrow.height + contentDimensions.height) [/code]

Comment: _inverted ? arrow.height : (borders.top.height + borders.bottom.height + arrow.height + contentDimensions.height)